# How to call Lisp functions Asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I currently have a .Net C# function which calls and passes a result buffer to a lisp function using `Application.Invoke()` (see [[AutoDesk]](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-in-dll-acad-exe/m-p/5522036/highlight/true#M43404)). The lisp function I am calling is neither AutoCAD native, nor is it an ARX/.Net function, so I cannot use the `Editor.Command`/`Editor.CommandAsync` methods, but the lisp code does call AutoCAD commands within the function. Is there a way to use the `Invoke()` or another method to call this function, without generating the dreaded `AutoCAD command rejected: ...` error?

Comment: You could wrap your synchronous invoke in a `Task.Run`.   Not really sure if it's the best idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The AutoLisp engine is synchronous only. You can use Lisp to call asynchronous commands/functions in ARX/.NET, but not the other way around. Even Task.Run will not perform the Lisp operation once the method exits.

The best approach is to convert all operations to ARX/.NET. If you want lisp to be a part of it, at least convert the operations that need to be asynchronous to ARX/.NET.